# magento 1.4 - have different subdomain route to same location

Tags: php, apache, magento

I am concerned this may not be possible (at least not easily) in Magento (1.4).

So we currently have a site set up:

```
shopping-public.mysite.com
```

Searching through `core_config_data` and the source code, shopping-public is referenced quite a few times.

What I want to accomplish is to have the following subdomain work on the same code base, AND have all the links between pages match up:

```
shopping-development.mysite.com
```

I have set up `ServerAlias shopping-development.mysite.com` in the .conf file, and **it works - that is, I'm getting there, and the page is being presented.**

However, it does NOT work in the sense that:
a) the references to the CSS files and JS files are still to `shop-public.mysite.com`, and
b) links to products and other pages are still to `shop-public.mysite.com`

How do I solve (a) and (b) so that, regardless of the subdomain (or even domain), asset file links and page links change relative to the (sub) domain I am on?

I am fairly new to Magento, and there are a LOT of xml values that reference this involved..

Answer (score 0):

Magento have a lot of configuration.

core_data
htaccess if use apache need test rewrite rules ok or no.
and maybe hardcoded index.php with switch case?

But firstly try clean cache.

Answer (score 0):

Magento will, as you can see, always attempt to redirect back to the primary domain.  To achieve this, I think you'd probably be best using different store views/sites and then using `.htaccess` to load the specific site required.

With this approach, there would be a concern over duplicate-content in Google's eyes I'm sure.